# Actix-web 2.0 JsonConfig error_handler not working

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have this below code, everything works expect the `error_handler`. I'm not sure whats wrong. If I make post request with correct format I get 200 with response data. But on bad request I'm expecting 400 with JSON data which is not receiving. It just says 400, but doesn't return any error json data.

#### Expected Behavior

BAD REQ -> `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"bad": "Someone was here"}' localhost:8080/send`

```
status 400
{
    error: String,
    server_id: usize,
    request_count: usize,
}
```

#### Current Behavior

BAD REQ -> `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"bad": "Someone was here"}' localhost:8080/send`

```
status 400
```

#### Possible Solution

I replaced `.data` with `.app_data` it works, but then it not able to find `AppState`

#### Code

```
pub struct MessageApp {
    pub port: u16,
}

impl MessageApp {
    pub fn new(port: u16) -> Self {
        Self{port}
    }

    pub async fn run(&self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let messages = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));
        println!("Starting http server: 127.0.0.1:{}", self.port);

        HttpServer::new(move || {
            App::new()
                .data(AppState {
                    server_id: SERVER_COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst),
                    request_count: Cell::new(0),
                    messages: messages.clone(),
                })
                .wrap(middleware::Logger::new(LOG_FORMAT))
                .service(index)
                .service(
                    web::resource("/send")
                    .data(
                        web::JsonConfig::default()
                            .limit(4096)
                            .error_handler(post_error)
                    )
                    .route(web::post().to(post))
                )
                .service(clear)
        })
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", self.port))?
        .workers(8)
        .run()
        .await
    }
}
```

**error handler**

```
fn post_error(err: JsonPayloadError, req: &HttpRequest) -> Error {
    let extns = req.extensions();
    let state = extns.get::<web::Data<AppState>>().unwrap();
    let request_count = state.request_count.get() + 1;
    state.request_count.set(request_count);

  let post_error = PostError {
      server_id: state.server_id,
      request_count,
      error: format!("{}", err),
  };

  InternalError::from_response(err, HttpResponse::BadRequest().json(post_error)).into()
}
```

#### Environment

- Pop OS 20.04 LTS
- Rust Version: rustc 1.45.2 (d3fb005a3 2020-07-31)
- Actix Web Version: 2.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned before in possible solutions.

After taking help from author on github. He mentioned I need to move out `.app_data` to get rid of this issue or move on to new version 3.0 which resolves this issue.

But using version 2.0.0 below is the solution:

```
HttpServer::new(move || {
            App::new()
                .data(AppState {
                    server_id: SERVER_COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst),
                    request_count: Cell::new(0),
                    messages: messages.clone(),
                })
                .wrap(middleware::Logger::new(LOG_FORMAT))
                .service(index)
                .service(
                    web::resource("/send")
                    .app_data(
                        web::JsonConfig::default().limit(4096).error_handler(post_error)
                    )
                    .route(web::post().to(post))
                )
                .service(clear)
        })
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", self.port))?
        .workers(8)
        .run()
        .await
```

As well the method for extracting AppState I was doing wrong. which fixed below inside **post_error** function.

```
fn post_error(err: JsonPayloadError, req: &HttpRequest) -> Error {
    // let extns = req.extensions();
    // let state = extns.get::<web::Data<AppState>>().unwrap();
    let state = req.app_data::<web::Data<AppState>>().unwrap();
    let request_count = state.request_count.get() + 1;
    state.request_count.set(request_count);

    let post_error = PostError {
        server_id: state.server_id,
        request_count,
        error: format!("{}", err),
    };

    InternalError::from_response(err, HttpResponse::BadRequest().json(post_error)).into()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. I guess you're also reading the book Fullstack Rust.